# C# Server socket bind / re-bind an endpoint when Ethernet is connected / disconnected

Tags: c#, tcp, .net-core, serversocket

**Background:**
I  have a `socket` server that binds to a specific IP address on the machines NIC. This works fine **IF** the NIC is connected to the client machine. Though, what I am having trouble with is an error-scenario where if the NIC is not connected to the client machine, it throws the following error: "`the requested address is not valid in its context`". This makes sense, because since there's no connection, the IP address cannot be assigned.

**Problem:**
How can I re-bind the `socket` so that once the NIC is physically connected to the client machine, the `socket` starts listening? Note that when I restart the program, it binds correctly and everything is fine. Though, I want to be able to restart the `socket` / re-bind without having to restart the program.

**Server Socket connection**:
I already have code where the connection is recalled every X seconds if it is determined that the socket is not bound (done in a background service). When I call the reconnect method (shown below), I still get the error.

```
var listeningSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listeningSocket.SetSocketOptions(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

// exception thrown here if NIC is not physically connected
//
listeningSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(address, port));
```

Comment: Create a timer that retries the connection every X seconds. Either you can use `System.Threading.Timer` (simplest way) or spawn off an `Action` that loops.

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks for the reply. i updated my question (i already have a mechanism that does the re-try.. though it's still throws the same error after i connect the Ethernet cable

Comment: It can take quite a long time to do the reconnect, 10-20 seconds or more. How long are you letting the retry timer go before you consider it not working after plugging the cable back in?